# Performance of range-based for in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Let's say `x` is a `vector<vector<int>>` and I want to compute the sum of the sizes of each element of `x`. It's a stupid example, but I want to ask if the methods above are equivalent to performance when the sizes of the elements of `x` are enough big.

```
// The first method:
int sum = 0;
for (vector<int> it : x)
    sum += it.size();

// The second method:
int sum = 0;
for (vector<int>& it : x)
    sum += it.size();
```

I think the second `for` is faster because it uses `&`, so the values of each element of `x` aren't copied to `it`. Am I right or both methods perform the same?

Comment: "I want to compute the sum of the sizes of each element of x" - Then you should be using [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I said it's a stupid example. The idea is that I want to do something with every element of `x`.

Comment: @IulianOleniuc what did you find out when you measured?

Comment: @eerorika, no major difference.

Comment: "I think the second for is faster because it uses &, so the values of each element of x aren't copied to it" - copying an integer is close to one of the cheapest things you can do. A reference is likely to be a pointer under-the-hood and while copying a pointer is also cheap, you also need to dereference it to get at the value it points to. I would expect that to be more expensive than just a `int` copy. *But*, for all things performance related; *test* and *benchmark*. And make sure to benchmark builds with optimizations *enabled*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `it` is a vector though; not an `int`.

Comment: @eerorika Whoops, I read it as a vector of ints being iterated. My bad.

Comment: imho it is much more important that the first code is not a good way of expressing what you want to do. "I want to compute the sum of the sizes of each element of x" is not the same as "I want to compute the sum of the sizes of copies of each element of x".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, that's correct. Accidentally copying into a ranged for loop variable is a particularly common problem when one is using `auto`:

```
for (auto it : x)
     sum += it.size();
```

That's inefficient since, even when using `auto` to automatically set the type and even though the iteration is over a set of `vector&`s, `it` ends up having type `vector`. (The solution there would be `auto&`, or even better, `auto const&`.)

Incidentally, the main performance sink here would not just be the copying of elements from inside `x` to your temporary `it`, but the allocation and deallocation of the memory used by `it`.

Comment: do you mean "... the allocation and deallocation of the memory used by `it`" ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the second `for` is faster. Quite a lot for large vectors. And it's very easy to bench it:

http://quick-bench.com/hR5VI3JwybDC0eBra6u8Ytd3uZ8

[image: Benchmark result]